# Xamarin Android push notifications not received after device re-boot

Tags: android, xamarin, push-notification, reboot

My Xamarin Android app used to receive push notifications after a device re-boot. When I started targeting API 33, devices no longer receive notifications after a re-boot until the app is restarted. I saw a comment on another post about this from Wendy Zang of MSFT that says this is because Google has deprecated WakefulBroadcastReceiver for security. The Android documentation says:

> In Android 8.0 (API 26 and above), Google placed limitations on what
> apps can do while users aren't directly interacting with them. These
> limitations affect background services and implicit broadcast
> receivers such as Android.Content.Intent.ActionBootCompleted. Because
> of these limitations, you might have difficulties registering a Boot
> Completed broadcast receiver on newer versions of Android. If this is
> the case, note that these restrictions do not apply to foreground
> services, which can be called from your broadcast receiver.

When targeting API 26 and above, what is necessary to get the app to receive push notifications after a device reboot, without having to launch the app? Can anyone please post an example?

Comment: Show the code you have, that worked on older version.